# SQL joining if id value is not existing another table

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have to join Several table and tables data are below:

[image: oc_product]

[image: oc_category]

[image: oc_category_description]

[image: oc_description]

[image: oc_product_description]

[image: oc_product_to_category]

[image: oc_product_special]

Here is want to show all product with both regular and special price which product_id maybe not be exist in oc_special table if not exist it will show 0.000 price in result.

Here is my what i am trying :

```
SELECT op.product_id, op.model, op.image, op.price, ops.price as discount_price, opc.category_id, opd.name as product_name, opd.description, ocd.name as cat_name FROM oc_product op INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category opc ON opc.product_id = op.product_id INNER JOIN oc_product_description opd ON opd.product_id = op.product_id INNER JOIN oc_category_description ocd ON ocd.category_id = opc.category_id Inner JOIN oc_product_special ops ON op.product_id = ops.product_id where op.status = 1 GROUP BY op.product_id
```

Here it only returns rows of items which are exists in oc_special table, but i want is to show all the product from oc_product table which product_id may not be exist in oc_special table.

Comment: (1) I am unclear on what your question is.  Although table layouts can be helpful, sample data and desired results are usually more helpful.  (2) What database are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you'll need an OUTER JOIN not an INNER JOIN?

Comment: What will be the query for that al_sweets

Comment: Suppose there are 8 products on oc_product table, and 4 product on oc_product_special table. now i want to show all those 8 products from oc_product table where 4 of them are not in oc_product_special table.
and i am using mysql database @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

If the results don't exist on ops table how do you expect to get `ops.price`?

Anyway, if your current query is working like you say it is, you can quickly check the `EXISTS`in the WHERE clause to filter the data.

```
SELECT op.product_id, op.model, op.image, op.price, ops.price as discount_price, opc.category_id, opd.name as product_name, opd.description, ocd.name as cat_name 
FROM oc_product op 
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category opc ON opc.product_id = op.product_id 
INNER JOIN oc_product_description opd ON opd.product_id = op.product_id 
INNER JOIN oc_category_description ocd ON ocd.category_id = opc.category_id 
INNER JOIN oc_product_special ops ON op.product_id = ops.product_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_special)
AND op.status = 1 
GROUP BY op.product_id
```

Comment: Suppose there are 8 products on oc_product table, and 4 product on oc_product_special table. now i want to show all those 8 products from oc_product table where 4 of them are not in oc_product_special table.